# Split String using Pattern and Matcher until first occurance of ','

Tags: java, regex

I want to split the below string in three parts 
(1) Number
(2) String until first occurance of ','
(3) Rest of the string

```
Like if the string is "12345 - electricity, flat no 1106 , Palash H , Pune"
Three parts should be 
(1) 12345
(2) electricity
(3) flat no 1106 , Palash H , Pune
```

I am able to split into 12345 and rest of the string using below code. but not able to break 2 and 3rd part as required

```
Map<String, String> strParts= new HashMap<String, String>();
String text = "12345 - electricity, flat no 1106 , Palash 2E , Pune";
Pattern pttrnCrs = Pattern.compile("(.*)\\s\\W\\s(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pttrnCrs.matcher(text);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    strParts.put("NUM", matcher.group(1));
    StrParts.put("REST", matcher.group(2));
}
```

Can any one help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a regex with 3 capturing groups:

```
^(\d+)\W*([^,]+)\h*,\h*(.*)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9lI0HS/1)

In Java use:

```
final String regex = "(\\d+)\\W*([^,]+)\\h*,\\h*(.*)";
```

No need to use anchors in Java if you are using `Matcher#matches()` method that implicitly anchors the regex.

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
^         # start
(\d+)     # match and group 1+ digits in group #1
\W*       # match 0 or more non-word characters
([^,]+)   # Match and group 1+ character that are not comma in group #2
\h*,\h*   # Match comma surrounded by optional whitespaces
(.*)      # match and group remaining characters in string in group #3
$         # end
```

Comment: Yes anubhava it worked. Can you please suggest me any sites/ learning material  to learn reg ex in Java. I am completely new to this area

Comment: You can follow this very good site to learn regex: http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: Thanks Anubhava
One more help needed, this code is working fine on my local but when I am running it on the Jenkins server I am getting below Errorjava.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 16
(\d+)\W*([^,]+)\h*,\h*(.*)
                ^
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924)
 Does it has to do any thing with Java Version

Comment: Yes `\h` is supported on Java 8. On older Java versions you can use: **`final String regex = "(\\d+)\\W*([^,]+)\\s*,\\s*(.*)";`**